# Сделать ре-import библиотеки

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Пишу код в `jupyter` так как я аналитик данных, сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, что когда что то добавляю в свою библиотеку, которую использую в текущем коде, она не обновляется в запущенном `jupyter` блокноте, приходится перезапускать ядро. Уходит много времени на перезапуск ячеек, как можно решить эту проблему? Обновлять библиотеку не перезапуская все, если повторно запустить ячейку с `import`, библиотека не обновляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка дубликат, мне лень искать. Обычно вот это вроде используется:

```py
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Взято с [англоязычного СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472712/8324991)